# Thinking_sphinx "begins_with" query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I need thinking_sphinx query to retrieve "begins_with" values. 
means if I give Student.search 'a', I want to display all student who have name starts with a.
I have indexed the name field already.Now, to retrieve a student, I have to give the exact name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want [wildcard searches](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/common_issues.html#wildcards). Either add this to your `config/sphinx.yml` file - or create it if you don't already have one:

```
development:
  enable_star: 1
  min_prefix_len: 1
# repeat for other environments
```

Or you can put it in a specific index - as infix/prefix settings increase the size of your indices dramatically:

```
define_index do
  # ...

  set_property :enable_star => 1
  set_property :min_prefix_len => 1
end
```

And then, run `rake ts:rebuild` so the changes are known by Sphinx and processed in the indices, and then you can search like this:

```
Student.search 'a*'
# or
Student.search :conditions => {:name => 'a*'}
```

And if you use min_infix_len instead of min_prefix_len, you can match **within** words as well - that is, put the star on either side:

```
Student.search '*a*'
```

Finally - if you **always** want your queries to have wildcard stars on each end of every term, use `:star => true` in your searches:

```
Student.search 'a b c', :star => true
# is the same as
Student.search '*a* *b* *c*'
```

Hope this helps you get the result you're looking for :)